# A nice way to find all combinations that give a sum of N?

Tags: python

Is there a nice way for generating a list of digits (0-9), with repetitions and a length of 6, such that the sum is N, say, 20. For example:

```
004673 -> 4+6+7+3=20
121673 -> 1+2+1+6+7+3=20
...
```

Thanks

Comment: Is this homework? What have you tried? Do you just want to know how to sum a string of digits, or are you trying to also generate such strings?

Comment: This is not homework -- I know it sounds like homework. The way I've done it is too inefficient. Actually I was being careless in the post -- indeed, I'm trying to generate those strings.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
['{0:06}'.format(i) for i in xrange(1000000) if sum(map(int,str(i))) == 20]
```

does the trick and needs about 5 seconds to return all 35127 numbers.

**UPDATE** - as a bonus, here comes the ugly-but-much-faster (~40 times faster) version:

```
result = []
for a in xrange(10):
    for b in xrange(10):
        for c in xrange(10):
            if a+b+c <= 20:
                for d in xrange(10):
                    if 2 < a+b+c+d <= 20:
                        for e in xrange(10):
                            if 10 < a+b+c+d+e <= 20:
                                f = 20 - (a+b+c+d+e)
                                result.append(''.join(map(str, [a,b,c,d,e,f])))
```

Comment: Very clever. And has the added bonus of being in-order. A quick `time.time()` check shows that there's very little difference between using the list comprehension or generator version, if you're just displaying all of these numbers.

Answer (score 7):

Much faster of other proposed solutions:

```
def iter_fun(sum, deepness, myString, Total):
    if deepness == 0:
        if sum == Total:
            print myString
    else:    
        for i in xrange(min(10, Total - sum + 1)):
            iter_fun(sum + i,deepness - 1,myString + str(i),Total) 

def fixed_sum_digits(digits, Tot):
    iter_fun(0,digits,"",Tot) 


fixed_sum_digits(6,20)
```

Still some room for speeder code but then the code would be boring to be read!

Comment: 35127 solutions, 169 if you count 060266 and 600266 only once.

Comment: It took a fraction of second (most of time spent for printing on screen). 
Vote the fastest and more elegant, please...

Comment: You can get a slight speedup by changing the `continue` to `break`.

Comment: +1.  I hope you don't mind that I optimized the loop a little bit.

Comment: I'm happy you did. Now I cannot see room for further optimization ;-)

Comment: @jimifiki Is there any way to return the list of digits in a list? Without defining a global variable?

Comment: @AlexP.Miller Thanks for the question. In iter_fun I would replace the print with an yield and in the last line of the function definition I would add the yield keyword just before calling iter_fun, along the lines of https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html#generators where recursive generators are introduced. Then you have to "reduce" the output. Let me know if you need suggestions for this part too.

Comment: @AlexP.Miller  I cannot edit my comment anymore so I elaborate here. [i for i in fixed_sum_digits(6, 20)] where iter_fun has "yield myString" and "yield from iter_fun(..." as fourth and seventh lines.

Answer (score 2):

Using `itertools` and permutations:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> l = []
>>> for digits in product('0123456789', repeat=6):
...     if sum(map(int, digits)) == 20:
...             l.append(digits)
...
>>> len(l)
35127
>>> l[1234]
('0', '1', '9', '0', '5', '5')
```

Seems to be a bit faster that eumiro's:

```
>>> stm = """l = []
... for digits in product('0123456789', repeat=6):
...     if sum(map(int, digits)) == 20:
...             l.append(digits)
... """
>>> timeit.timeit(stm, setup="from itertools import product", number=3)
10.368315935134888
>>> timeit.timeit("['{0:06}'.format(i) for i in xrange(1000000) if sum(map(int,str(i))) == 20]", number=3)
14.926225900650024
```

Comment: "repmutation" sounds like it could be some serious stackoverflow bug o.O

Comment: Wouldn't `combinations_with_replacement('0123456789', repeat=6)` be faster? I think it would give 169 results  but I can't test (Python 2.6.5 does not seem to have combinations_with_replacement).

Comment: @steenslag yeah, I thought about it, but I use Python 2.6 too:)