# How to generate a set of all tuples of given length and sum of elements?

Tags: python, recursion, combinatorics

I would like to have a function that generates a set (or a list) of all possible tuples with a given length and sum of their elements. The elements of tuples should be not negative integer.

For example for the following input

```
get_tuple(length=3, total=2)
```

I would like to get the following output:

```
[(1, 0, 1), (2, 0, 0), (1, 1, 0), (0, 0, 2), (0, 1, 1), (0, 2, 0)]
```

Is the a standard library in Python that can do that? If not, how to write a function that can do it?

Comment: recursion would be probably one of the more efficient ways to solve your problem

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8617455/a-nice-way-to-find-all-combinations-that-give-a-sum-of-n

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a recursive function, avoiding creating all candidate combinations and checking their sums:

```
def get_tuples(length, total):
    if length == 1:
        yield (total,)
        return

    for i in xrange(total + 1):
        for t in get_tuples(length - 1, total - i):
            yield (i,) + t
```

If we test:

```
>>> list(get_tuples(3, 2))
[(0, 0, 2), (0, 1, 1), (0, 2, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 0), (2, 0, 0)]
```

Comment: why not use tuples?  `yield (total,)`

Comment: Now `get_tuple` gets tuples ;)

Comment: If you are using python 3 you can `yield from ((i,) + t for i in range(total + 1) for t in get_tuples(length - 1, total - i))`

Answer (score 4):

you can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to get the product of all numbers then use filter function for select that products that has specified sum :

```
>>> def get_tuple(length, total):
...     return filter(lambda x:sum(x)==total,product(range(total+1),repeat=length))
... 
>>> get_tuple(3, 2)
[(0, 0, 2), (0, 1, 1), (0, 2, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 0), (2, 0, 0)]
>>> get_tuple(4, 12)
[(0, 0, 0, 12), (0, 0, 1, 11), (0, 0, 2, 10), (0, 0, 3, 9), (0, 0, 4, 8), (0, 0, 5, 7), (0, 0, 6, 6), (0, 0, 7, 5), (0, 0, 8, 4), (0, 0, 9, 3), (0, 0, 10, 2), (0, 0, 11, 1), (0, 0, 12, 0), (0, 1, 0, 11), (0, 1, 1, 10), (0, 1, 2, 9), (0, 1, 3, 8), (0, 1, 4, 7), (0, 1, 5, 6), (0, 1, 6, 5), (0, 1, 7, 4), (0, 1, 8, 3), (0, 1, 9, 2), (0, 1, 10, 1), (0, 1, 11, 0), (0, 2, 0, 10), (0, 2, 1, 9), (0, 2, 2, 8), (0, 2, 3, 7), (0, 2, 4, 6), (0, 2, 5, 5), (0, 2, 6, 4), (0, 2, 7, 3), (0, 2, 8, 2), (0, 2, 9, 1), (0, 2, 10, 0), (0, 3, 0, 9), (0, 3, 1, 8), (0, 3, 2, 7), (0, 3, 3, 6), (0, 3, 4, 5), (0, 3, 5, 4), (0, 3, 6, 3), (0, 3, 7, 2), (0, 3, 8, 1), (0, 3, 9, 0), (0, 4, 0, 8), (0, 4, 1, 7), (0, 4, 2, 6), (0, 4, 3, 5), (0, 4, 4, 4), (0, 4, 5, 3), (0, 4, 6, 2), (0, 4, 7, 1), (0, 4, 8, 0), (0, 5, 0, 7), (0, 5, 1, 6), (0, 5, 2, 5), (0, 5, 3, 4), (0, 5, 4, 3), (0, 5, 5, 2), (0, 5, 6, 1), (0, 5, 7, 0), (0, 6, 0, 6), (0, 6, 1, 5), (0, 6, 2, 4), (0, 6, 3, 3), (0, 6, 4, 2), (0, 6, 5, 1), (0, 6, 6, 0), (0, 7, 0, 5), (0, 7, 1, 4), (0, 7, 2, 3), (0, 7, 3, 2), (0, 7, 4, 1), (0, 7, 5, 0), (0, 8, 0, 4), (0, 8, 1, 3), (0, 8, 2, 2), (0, 8, 3, 1), (0, 8, 4, 0), (0, 9, 0, 3), (0, 9, 1, 2), (0, 9, 2, 1), (0, 9, 3, 0), (0, 10, 0, 2), (0, 10, 1, 1), (0, 10, 2, 0), (0, 11, 0, 1), (0, 11, 1, 0), (0, 12, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0, 11), (1, 0, 1, 10), (1, 0, 2, 9), (1, 0, 3, 8), (1, 0, 4, 7), (1, 0, 5, 6), (1, 0, 6, 5), (1, 0, 7, 4), (1, 0, 8, 3), (1, 0, 9, 2), (1, 0, 10, 1), (1, 0, 11, 0), (1, 1, 0, 10), (1, 1, 1, 9), (1, 1, 2, 8), (1, 1, 3, 7), (1, 1, 4, 6), (1, 1, 5, 5), (1, 1, 6, 4), (1, 1, 7, 3), (1, 1, 8, 2), (1, 1, 9, 1), (1, 1, 10, 0), (1, 2, 0, 9), (1, 2, 1, 8), (1, 2, 2, 7), (1, 2, 3, 6), (1, 2, 4, 5), (1, 2, 5, 4), (1, 2, 6, 3), (1, 2, 7, 2), (1, 2, 8, 1), (1, 2, 9, 0), (1, 3, 0, 8), (1, 3, 1, 7), (1, 3, 2, 6), (1, 3, 3, 5), (1, 3, 4, 4), (1, 3, 5, 3), (1, 3, 6, 2), (1, 3, 7, 1), (1, 3, 8, 0), (1, 4, 0, 7), (1, 4, 1, 6), (1, 4, 2, 5), (1, 4, 3, 4), (1, 4, 4, 3), (1, 4, 5, 2), (1, 4, 6, 1), (1, 4, 7, 0), (1, 5, 0, 6), (1, 5, 1, 5), (1, 5, 2, 4), (1, 5, 3, 3), (1, 5, 4, 2), (1, 5, 5, 1), (1, 5, 6, 0), (1, 6, 0, 5), (1, 6, 1, 4), (1, 6, 2, 3), (1, 6, 3, 2), (1, 6, 4, 1), (1, 6, 5, 0), (1, 7, 0, 4), (1, 7, 1, 3), (1, 7, 2, 2), (1, 7, 3, 1), (1, 7, 4, 0), (1, 8, 0, 3), (1, 8, 1, 2), (1, 8, 2, 1), (1, 8, 3, 0), (1, 9, 0, 2), (1, 9, 1, 1), (1, 9, 2, 0), (1, 10, 0, 1), (1, 10, 1, 0), (1, 11, 0, 0), (2, 0, 0, 10), (2, 0, 1, 9), (2, 0, 2, 8), (2, 0, 3, 7), (2, 0, 4, 6), (2, 0, 5, 5), (2, 0, 6, 4), (2, 0, 7, 3), (2, 0, 8, 2), (2, 0, 9, 1), (2, 0, 10, 0), (2, 1, 0, 9), (2, 1, 1, 8), (2, 1, 2, 7), (2, 1, 3, 6), (2, 1, 4, 5), (2, 1, 5, 4), (2, 1, 6, 3), (2, 1, 7, 2), (2, 1, 8, 1), (2, 1, 9, 0), (2, 2, 0, 8), (2, 2, 1, 7), (2, 2, 2, 6), (2, 2, 3, 5), (2, 2, 4, 4), (2, 2, 5, 3), (2, 2, 6, 2), (2, 2, 7, 1), (2, 2, 8, 0), (2, 3, 0, 7), (2, 3, 1, 6), (2, 3, 2, 5), (2, 3, 3, 4), (2, 3, 4, 3), (2, 3, 5, 2), (2, 3, 6, 1), (2, 3, 7, 0), (2, 4, 0, 6), (2, 4, 1, 5), (2, 4, 2, 4), (2, 4, 3, 3), (2, 4, 4, 2), (2, 4, 5, 1), (2, 4, 6, 0), (2, 5, 0, 5), (2, 5, 1, 4), (2, 5, 2, 3), (2, 5, 3, 2), (2, 5, 4, 1), (2, 5, 5, 0), (2, 6, 0, 4), (2, 6, 1, 3), (2, 6, 2, 2), (2, 6, 3, 1), (2, 6, 4, 0), (2, 7, 0, 3), (2, 7, 1, 2), (2, 7, 2, 1), (2, 7, 3, 0), (2, 8, 0, 2), (2, 8, 1, 1), (2, 8, 2, 0), (2, 9, 0, 1), (2, 9, 1, 0), (2, 10, 0, 0), (3, 0, 0, 9), (3, 0, 1, 8), (3, 0, 2, 7), (3, 0, 3, 6), (3, 0, 4, 5), (3, 0, 5, 4), (3, 0, 6, 3), (3, 0, 7, 2), (3, 0, 8, 1), (3, 0, 9, 0), (3, 1, 0, 8), (3, 1, 1, 7), (3, 1, 2, 6), (3, 1, 3, 5), (3, 1, 4, 4), (3, 1, 5, 3), (3, 1, 6, 2), (3, 1, 7, 1), (3, 1, 8, 0), (3, 2, 0, 7), (3, 2, 1, 6), (3, 2, 2, 5), (3, 2, 3, 4), (3, 2, 4, 3), (3, 2, 5, 2), (3, 2, 6, 1), (3, 2, 7, 0), (3, 3, 0, 6), (3, 3, 1, 5), (3, 3, 2, 4), (3, 3, 3, 3), (3, 3, 4, 2), (3, 3, 5, 1), (3, 3, 6, 0), (3, 4, 0, 5), (3, 4, 1, 4), (3, 4, 2, 3), (3, 4, 3, 2), (3, 4, 4, 1), (3, 4, 5, 0), (3, 5, 0, 4), (3, 5, 1, 3), (3, 5, 2, 2), (3, 5, 3, 1), (3, 5, 4, 0), (3, 6, 0, 3), (3, 6, 1, 2), (3, 6, 2, 1), (3, 6, 3, 0), (3, 7, 0, 2), (3, 7, 1, 1), (3, 7, 2, 0), (3, 8, 0, 1), (3, 8, 1, 0), (3, 9, 0, 0), (4, 0, 0, 8), (4, 0, 1, 7), (4, 0, 2, 6), (4, 0, 3, 5), (4, 0, 4, 4), (4, 0, 5, 3), (4, 0, 6, 2), (4, 0, 7, 1), (4, 0, 8, 0), (4, 1, 0, 7), (4, 1, 1, 6), (4, 1, 2, 5), (4, 1, 3, 4), (4, 1, 4, 3), (4, 1, 5, 2), (4, 1, 6, 1), (4, 1, 7, 0), (4, 2, 0, 6), (4, 2, 1, 5), (4, 2, 2, 4), (4, 2, 3, 3), (4, 2, 4, 2), (4, 2, 5, 1), (4, 2, 6, 0), (4, 3, 0, 5), (4, 3, 1, 4), (4, 3, 2, 3), (4, 3, 3, 2), (4, 3, 4, 1), (4, 3, 5, 0), (4, 4, 0, 4), (4, 4, 1, 3), (4, 4, 2, 2), (4, 4, 3, 1), (4, 4, 4, 0), (4, 5, 0, 3), (4, 5, 1, 2), (4, 5, 2, 1), (4, 5, 3, 0), (4, 6, 0, 2), (4, 6, 1, 1), (4, 6, 2, 0), (4, 7, 0, 1), (4, 7, 1, 0), (4, 8, 0, 0), (5, 0, 0, 7), (5, 0, 1, 6), (5, 0, 2, 5), (5, 0, 3, 4), (5, 0, 4, 3), (5, 0, 5, 2), (5, 0, 6, 1), (5, 0, 7, 0), (5, 1, 0, 6), (5, 1, 1, 5), (5, 1, 2, 4), (5, 1, 3, 3), (5, 1, 4, 2), (5, 1, 5, 1), (5, 1, 6, 0), (5, 2, 0, 5), (5, 2, 1, 4), (5, 2, 2, 3), (5, 2, 3, 2), (5, 2, 4, 1), (5, 2, 5, 0), (5, 3, 0, 4), (5, 3, 1, 3), (5, 3, 2, 2), (5, 3, 3, 1), (5, 3, 4, 0), (5, 4, 0, 3), (5, 4, 1, 2), (5, 4, 2, 1), (5, 4, 3, 0), (5, 5, 0, 2), (5, 5, 1, 1), (5, 5, 2, 0), (5, 6, 0, 1), (5, 6, 1, 0), (5, 7, 0, 0), (6, 0, 0, 6), (6, 0, 1, 5), (6, 0, 2, 4), (6, 0, 3, 3), (6, 0, 4, 2), (6, 0, 5, 1), (6, 0, 6, 0), (6, 1, 0, 5), (6, 1, 1, 4), (6, 1, 2, 3), (6, 1, 3, 2), (6, 1, 4, 1), (6, 1, 5, 0), (6, 2, 0, 4), (6, 2, 1, 3), (6, 2, 2, 2), (6, 2, 3, 1), (6, 2, 4, 0), (6, 3, 0, 3), (6, 3, 1, 2), (6, 3, 2, 1), (6, 3, 3, 0), (6, 4, 0, 2), (6, 4, 1, 1), (6, 4, 2, 0), (6, 5, 0, 1), (6, 5, 1, 0), (6, 6, 0, 0), (7, 0, 0, 5), (7, 0, 1, 4), (7, 0, 2, 3), (7, 0, 3, 2), (7, 0, 4, 1), (7, 0, 5, 0), (7, 1, 0, 4), (7, 1, 1, 3), (7, 1, 2, 2), (7, 1, 3, 1), (7, 1, 4, 0), (7, 2, 0, 3), (7, 2, 1, 2), (7, 2, 2, 1), (7, 2, 3, 0), (7, 3, 0, 2), (7, 3, 1, 1), (7, 3, 2, 0), (7, 4, 0, 1), (7, 4, 1, 0), (7, 5, 0, 0), (8, 0, 0, 4), (8, 0, 1, 3), (8, 0, 2, 2), (8, 0, 3, 1), (8, 0, 4, 0), (8, 1, 0, 3), (8, 1, 1, 2), (8, 1, 2, 1), (8, 1, 3, 0), (8, 2, 0, 2), (8, 2, 1, 1), (8, 2, 2, 0), (8, 3, 0, 1), (8, 3, 1, 0), (8, 4, 0, 0), (9, 0, 0, 3), (9, 0, 1, 2), (9, 0, 2, 1), (9, 0, 3, 0), (9, 1, 0, 2), (9, 1, 1, 1), (9, 1, 2, 0), (9, 2, 0, 1), (9, 2, 1, 0), (9, 3, 0, 0), (10, 0, 0, 2), (10, 0, 1, 1), (10, 0, 2, 0), (10, 1, 0, 1), (10, 1, 1, 0), (10, 2, 0, 0), (11, 0, 0, 1), (11, 0, 1, 0), (11, 1, 0, 0), (12, 0, 0, 0)]
>>>
```

Comment: When I use `get_tuple(4,12)` I get `[(3, 3, 3, 3)]`, but I expect to see the tuples like [(7,1,2,2)].

Comment: I think `range(length)` has to be replaced by `range(total + 1)`. Isn't?

Comment: @Roman roman i write the answer based on your question! you can change it based on the logic in your mind!

Comment: And for down voter : i like to hear about the problem with my code till i refine it and get a better answer to community and OP!

Comment: in my question I wanted to have a function that return "all possible tuples with the given length and sum of elements". Your solution seems to do something different. For example it does not return all tuples with length 4 and sum 12 (it gives just one tuple, but there is obviously more).