# Map an element in a multi-dimension array to its index

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I am using the function `get_tuples(length, total)` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29170953/how-to-generate-a-set-of-all-tuples-of-given-length-and-sum-of-elements)
to generate an array of all tuples of given length and sum, an example and the function are shown below. After I have created the array I need to find a way to return the indices of a given number of elements in the array. I was able to do that using `.index()` by changing the array to a list, as shown below. However, this solution or another solution that is also based on searching (for example using `np.where`) takes a lot of time to find the indices. Since all elements in the array (array `s` in the example) are different, I was wondering if we can construct a one-to-one mapping, i.e., a function such that given the element in the array it returns the index of the element by doing some addition and multiplication on the values of this element. Any ideas if that is possible? Thanks!

```py
import numpy as np

def get_tuples(length, total):
    if length == 1:
        yield (total,)
        return

    for i in range(total + 1):
        for t in get_tuples(length - 1, total - i):
            yield (i,) + t
#example
s = np.array(list(get_tuples(4, 20)))

# array s
In [1]: s
Out[1]: 
array([[ 0,  0,  0, 20],
       [ 0,  0,  1, 19],
       [ 0,  0,  2, 18],
       ...,
       [19,  0,  1,  0],
       [19,  1,  0,  0],
       [20,  0,  0,  0]])

#example of element to find the index for. (Note in reality this is 1000+ elements)
elements_to_find =np.array([[ 0,  0,  0, 20],
                            [ 0,  0,  7, 13],
                            [ 0,  5,  5, 10],
                            [ 0,  0,  5, 15],
                            [ 0,  2,  4, 14]])
#change array to list
s_list = s.tolist()

#find the indices
indx=[s_list.index(i) for i in elements_to_find.tolist()]

#output
In [2]: indx
Out[2]: [0, 7, 100, 5, 45]
```

Comment: Do you have access to the input of `get_tuples()`?

Comment: Do you mean the parameters 4 and 20 in the example? Yes I set those.

Comment: OK, but then why can't you just compute the order of appearance of the elements to find using that information?

Comment: How would you do that? That's exactly what I'm trying to find. There should be a formula that given an element in the array for example `[0, 0, 0, 20]` gives back 0,...etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a formula that calculates the index based on the tuple alone, i.e. it needn't see the full array. To compute the index of an N-tuple it needs to evaluate N-1 binomial coefficients. The following implementation is (part-) vectorized, it accepts ND-arrays but the tuples must be in the last dimension.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import comb

# unfortunately, comb with option exact=True is not vectorized
def bc(N,k):
    return np.round(comb(N,k)).astype(int)

def get_idx(s):
    N = s.shape[-1] - 1
    R = np.arange(1,N)
    ps = s[...,::-1].cumsum(-1)
    B = bc(ps[...,1:-1]+R,1+R)
    return bc(ps[...,-1]+N,N) - ps[...,0] - 1 - B.sum(-1)

# OP's generator
def get_tuples(length, total):
    if length == 1:
        yield (total,)
        return

    for i in range(total + 1):
        for t in get_tuples(length - 1, total - i):
            yield (i,) + t
#example
s = np.array(list(get_tuples(4, 20)))

# compute each index
r = get_idx(s)

# expected: 0,1,2,3,...
assert (r == np.arange(len(r))).all()
print("all ok")

#example of element to find the index for. (Note in reality this is 1000+ elements)
elements_to_find =np.array([[ 0,  0,  0, 20],
                            [ 0,  0,  7, 13],
                            [ 0,  5,  5, 10],
                            [ 0,  0,  5, 15],
                            [ 0,  2,  4, 14]])

print(get_idx(elements_to_find))
```

Sample run:

```
all ok
[  0   7 100   5  45]
```

How to derive formula:

1. Use [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29) to express the full partition count `#part(N,k)` (N is total, k is length) as a single binomial coefficient `(N + k - 1) choose (k - 1)`.
2. Count back-to-front: It is not hard to verify that after the i-th full iteration of the outer loop of OP's generator exactly `#part(N-i,k)` have not yet been enumerated. Indeed, what's left are all partitions p1+p2+... = N with p1>=i; we can write p1=q1+i such that q1+p2+... = N-i and this latter partition is constraint-free so we can use 1. to count.

Comment: Perhaps this would be better with some more explanation of `get_idx()`

Comment: I found out you can make it slightly faster by using `binom` instead of `comb`. `from scipy.special import binom`

`def bc(N,k):
    return np.round(binom(N,k)).astype(int)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use binary search to make the search a lot faster.

Binary search makes the search O(log(n)) rather than O(n) (using Index)

We do not need to sort the tuples since they are already sorted by the generator

```
import bisect

def get_tuples(length, total):
  " Generates tuples "
  if length == 1:
    yield (total,)
    return

  yield from ((i,) + t for i in range(total + 1) for t in get_tuples(length - 1, total - i))

def find_indexes(x, indexes):
   if len(indexes) > 100:
        # Faster to generate all indexes when we have a large
        # number to check
        d = dict(zip(x, range(len(x))))
        return [d[tuple(i)] for i in indexes]
    else:
        return [bisect.bisect_left(x, tuple(i)) for i in indexes]

# Generate tuples (in this case 4, 20)
x = list(get_tuples(4, 20))

# Tuples are generated in sorted order [(0,0,0,20), ...(20,0,0,0)]
# which allows binary search to be used
indexes = [[ 0,  0,  0, 20],
           [ 0,  0,  7, 13],
           [ 0,  5,  5, 10],
           [ 0,  0,  5, 15],
           [ 0,  2,  4, 14]]

y = find_indexes(x, indexes)
print('Found indexes:', *y)
print('Indexes & Tuples:')
for i in y:
  print(i, x[i])
```

Output

```
Found indexes: 0 7 100 5 45
Indexes & Tuples:
0 (0, 0, 0, 20)
7 (0, 0, 7, 13)
100 (0, 5, 5, 10)
5 (0, 0, 5, 15)
45 (0, 2, 4, 14)
```

**Performance**

*Scenario 1*--Tuples already computed and we just want to find the index of certain tuples

For instance x = list(get_tuples(4, 20)) has already been perform.

Search for

```
indexes = [[ 0,  0,  0, 20],
           [ 0,  0,  7, 13],
           [ 0,  5,  5, 10],
           [ 0,  0,  5, 15],
           [ 0,  2,  4, 14]]
```

Binary Search

```
%timeit find_indexes(x, indexes)
100000 loops, best of 3: 11.2 µs per loop
```

Calculates the index based on the tuple alone (courtesy @PaulPanzer approach)

```
%timeit get_idx(indexes)
10000 loops, best of 3: 92.7 µs per loop
```

In this scenario, binary search is ~8x faster when tuples have already been pre-computed.

*Scenario 2*--the tuples have not been pre-computed.

```
%%timeit
import bisect

def find_indexes(x, t):
    " finds the index of each tuple in list t (assumes x is sorted) "
    return [bisect.bisect_left(x, tuple(i)) for i in t]

# Generate tuples (in this case 4, 20)
x = list(get_tuples(4, 20))

indexes = [[ 0,  0,  0, 20],
           [ 0,  0,  7, 13],
           [ 0,  5,  5, 10],
           [ 0,  0,  5, 15],
           [ 0,  2,  4, 14]]

y = find_indexes(x, indexes)

100 loops, best of 3: 2.69 ms per loop
```

@PaulPanzer approach is the same timing in this scenario (92.97 us)

=> @PaulPanzer approach ~29 times faster when the tuples don't have to be computed

*Scenario 3*--Large number of indexes (@PJORR)
A large number of random indexes is generated

```
x = list(get_tuples(4, 20))
xnp = np.array(x)
indices = xnp[np.random.randint(0,len(xnp), 2000)]
indexes = indices.tolist()
%timeit find_indexes(x, indexes)
#Result: 1000 loops, best of 3: 1.1 ms per loop
%timeit get_idx(indices)
#Result: 1000 loops, best of 3: 716 µs per loop
```

In this case, we are @PaulPanzer is 53% faster

Comment: What is the function find_indexes?

Comment: @PJORR--thanks, I somehow missed including it since it was just one line.

Comment: Thanks! From my experimentation I found that @PaulPanzer approach is 3x faster when the length of `indexes` is 1000+ even if `x = list(get_tuples(4, 20))` have been already performed. May be the usage of both approaches should be decided based on how many elements to find.

Comment: @PJORR--interesting.  But, my test was with get_tuples(4, 20) which has 1721 indexes.  Wonder why in that case my measurement shows that bisection was faster.  My measurement was using code was as shown using Jupyter notebooks.  Are you using the updated algorithm where I removed sort since it was unnecessary?

Comment: I am not talking about 'get_tuples(4,20)'. I mean try the above experiment with indexes (the elements to lookup their indices) have a shape of  `(2000,4)` instead of `(5,4)`. For example: `xnp = np.array(x)`, `indices = xnp[np.random.randint(0,len(xnp),2000)]`, `indexes = indices.tolist()`, then compare `%timeit get_idx(indices)` and `%timeit find_indexes(x,indexes)`.

Comment: Nice! Can you please add the memoization part to your answer if possible.

Comment: @PJORR--deleted my earlier claim since I may not have tested properly.  I'm reevaluating the code.

Comment: @PJORR--updated solution to make more comparable when you have a large number of indexes.  Rather than 300%, get_idx is 53% faster in this case.  Gained some ground by creating a dictionary with all indexes when the number of indexes is large.

Comment: That's great! Thanks

Comment: If the dictionary `d` is precomputed and provided as a parameter to the function instead of computing it inside `find_indexes`, then both achieves the same time.

Comment: @PJORR--sounds right.  But, actually, I thought we could just switch between the two solutions based upon the size of indexes.  Meaning switch between find_indexes and get_idx depending upon size of indexes.

Comment: Yep, that would be perfect.